# Extensive list of Jenkins job statuses?

Tags: java, python, jenkins

I am using [jenkinsapi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi) for python for some analysis of a big load of Jenkins jobs. Depending on the status of the jobs, I want to do different things with each of them. Is there some sort of overview over all possible statuses a Jenkins job can have? I would like to have that, so that I can handle each case differently. So far, I have only encountered "SUCCESS", "FAILURE", and "UNSTABLE".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the source code at [Result.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Result.java) you have 
SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, FAILURE, NOT_BUILT or ABORTED.